# Can't display images on html page from database

Tags: python, django, media

I see  only icons with urls like /media/image.jpg. I think problem in urls.py, but I don't know how to resolve it. Can someone help me?

settings.py:

```
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
....
```

models.py:

```
....
class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product)
    top_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', verbose_name ="Главное изображение")
    second_image = models.ImageField(blank = True, verbose_name = "Изображение 2")
    third_image = models.ImageField(blank = True, verbose_name = "Изображение 3")
    fourth_image = models.ImageField(blank = True, verbose_name = "Изображение 4")
    fifth_image = models.ImageField(blank = True, verbose_name = "Изображение 5")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.product

    class Meta():
        db_table = "Image"
...
```

articles.html

```
...
 {% for image in product_images %}
         <div>
            <img src="{{ image.top_image.url }}">
         </div>
         {% endfor %}
...
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mypoject.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^', 'article.views.articles'),
    )
```

Comment: By visiting `localhost:8000/media/image.jpg` you can access but in template not, Is that question.?

Comment: when I visit localhost:8000/media/ image.jpg I see  localhost:8000/ page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add this in your urls.py file :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Be carreful you have to use it only for dev : [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: I've tried it, but without result.                                                                 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mypoject.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^', 'article.views.articles'),
    )+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: And I also try  <img src="/home/evgeny/wonderful_programming/djangoenv/bin/django_Shop{{ image.top_image.url}})">

Comment: normally your image should be stored in MEDIA_ROOT/media. Could you check the file is here. Moreover, what is content of {{ image.top_image.url }} ?

Comment: Images is stored in ..myproject_name/media/ dir.  {{ image.top_image.url }} = /media/image.jpg

Comment: Got it, I think it is because of `url(r'^', 'article.views.articles')`, your /media/image.jpg matches with it. Try to modify it with `url(r'^$', 'article.views.articles')`

Answer (score 0):

`/media/image.jpg` is a relative url.

To get the absolute uri you need something like this `request.build_absolute_uri(obj.image.url)`

You can read further informations [here in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/)